# Html Image won't show up in site. Line invisible when inspect

Tags: html, css, image

So, I'm using Neocities to create a site. I have put images in my site and it has worked perfectly fine before, but now that i try and place an image under the one i already put and it doesn't show up on the site, the line of code used to display said image doesn't even appear in the code, I've done all I could without bringing up an error, adding "'s and >'s where they work to no avail,

```css
  img.a {
  width 100px height 400px object-position: 900px
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.centerimage {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 15%;
}

.divider {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 10%;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/602568582403981341/886027448423161886/ezgif-7-cb6f256f81b8.gif");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: cover;
  background-size: 800px 900px
}

.font1 {
  font-family: "Blackadder ITC", "Lucida Handwriting"
}

.small {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.eyes {
```

```html
<p class="center font1 small" style="color:white;"> Hello, i wish you welcome, and a great stay on my site! This little (unfinished) spec of the interweb shall serve many purposes;</p>

<img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/0b7a7e88c43cc20b5e68fd44a6297b83/85e01a52885fa806-1c/s250x400/d1d3dc319ac3203a5aa797f403a2704e2bed22d6.gif" class="divider">

<p class="center font1 small" style="color:white;"> A blog, a gallery for my art and edits, a place to note and host qnas regarding the world of Thanatos, and a dictionary for my conlang!</p>

<img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/0b7a7e88c43cc20b5e68fd44a6297b83/85e01a52885fa806-1c/s250x400/d1d3dc319ac3203a5aa797f403a2704e2bed22d6.gif" class="divider">

<img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/602568582403981341/886040128714342430/thanats.png" class="centerimage">

<img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/0b7a7e88c43cc20b5e68fd44a6297b83/85e01a52885fa806-1c/s250x400/d1d3dc319ac3203a5aa797f403a2704e2bed22d6.gif" class="divider">

<center><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/602568582403981341/886096670209761360/thanatoscal_1.png" class="centerimage"> </center>
```

Comment: btw you got `.eyes {` which it's uncompleted/and not closed in `<style>`

Comment: not that `<center>` is not a tag that exist within HTML5. It is obsolete since the release of HTML5.